# How to know if my macOS app is in background or in foreground?

Tags: swift, macos, nsapplication, nsworkspace

I would like to know with Swift, if my macOS app is running in the background of in foreground.

I found different ways (for example here:  [Is there any way to check if iOS app is in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835806/is-there-any-way-to-check-if-ios-app-is-in-background) ) related to iOS apps, but not for modern macOS.

It would be great if there was also for macOS a way similar to this one:

```
   let state = NSApplication.applicationState
   if state == .background { // doesn't work
    // do something here
   }
```

Comment: Did you check the properties of [NSApplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication?language=objc)?

Answer (score 4):

I found this way:

```
    let application = NSApplication.shared
    let state = application.isActive

    if state {
        print("app in foreground")
    }
```